# How do I make discord bot send a message at a specific time and date (in Python)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a discord bot and I want to make some kind of an announcement system.
Basically user inputs message and date & time on which the message would be send to a specific channel.

I can't figure how to do it.

Comment: Jacques, I thought of making a function wich takes hour,minute,year,month,day (on wich message would be send) and calls another function wich takes the message. But I kinda got stuck on how to make date arguments optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using datetime and json module, the thing can be solved.

First take date and time argument from user and store it in a json file.

Now make a function that compares the dates in the json file with current time.

Next call that function with every command to make it update every time.

If time in json file = current time, send Announcement!

If you want you can erase the data in the json file as soon as the specific announcement is sent, or leave it like that if you want that announcement to be sent everyday at the specified time.